# How to send a object array with promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I have tried a lot and didn't get anything that works good for me.
I tried with promise.all and setting the array globally, but with no success.

I want to search in three collections on MongoDB and when the find matches, set an object with the infos and push to an array. At the end, send a response with the objects array.

```
router.post('/certificado', (req, res) => {
  let cpf = splita(req.body.cpf)
  let array = []

  function pesquisaProjeto(cpf) {
    return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
      ProjetoSchema.find({'integrantes.cpf':cpf}, 'integrantes.$ nomeProjeto -_id',(err, usr) => {
        if (err) return reject(err)
        fulfill(usr)
      });
    })
  }

  function pesquisaAvaliador(cpf) {
    return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
      avaliadorSchema.find({'cpf':cpf}, 'nome -_id',(err, usr) => {
        if (err) return reject(err)
        fulfill(usr)
      })
    })
  }

  function pesquisaParticipante(cpf) {
    return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
      participanteSchema.find({'cpf':cpf}, 'nome eventos -_id', (err, usr) => {
        if (err) return reject(err)
        fulfill(usr)
      })
    })
  }

  pesquisaProjeto(cpf)
  .then(usr => {
    let participante = ({
      tipo: usr[0].integrantes[0].tipo,
      nome: usr[0].integrantes[0].nome
    })
    array.push(participante)
    console.log(participante)
  })
  .catch(err => console.log("Não encontrou nada nos projetos. " + err.message))

  pesquisaAvaliador(cpf)
  .then(usr => {
    let participante = {
      tipo: "Avaliador",
      nome: usr[0].nome
    }
    array.push(participante)
    console.log(array)
  })
  .catch(err => console.log("Não encontrou nada nos avaliadores. " + err.message))

  pesquisaParticipante(cpf)
  .then(usr => {
    let participante = ({
      tipo: "Participante",
      nome: usr[0].nome,
      eventos: usr[0].eventos
    })
    array.push(participante)
    console.log(array)
  })
  .catch(err => console.log("Não encontrou nada nos participantes dos eventos. " + err.message))

    **Anything like res.send(array) that I was tired to try**
});
```

Sorry for the stupid doubt, but I've spent so much time trying to find the solution that I decided to resort to the community.

Thanks!

Comment: why didn't `promise.all` work?

Comment: Don't know. When I try to `res.send(array)` at the `.then()` of `promise.all` nothing is sended to front. Think that could be some wrong with the push inside the promise and the array declaration.

Comment: Please show us how you tried to use `Promise.all`.

Comment: @RicardoSwarovsky add your solution as an answer, not an edit to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right you have multiple promises and want to wait for all of them to finish. You can do that with `Promise.all()`.

If one Promise will fail Promise.all() will also fail. But if you catch them like you do in your example and return nothing I think the Array should be populated with undefined for that Query. So you could then filter those empty values out if you want to.

```
const one = dbQueryOne.then(usr => ({
  key: usr.val
}))
.catch(err => { console.log(err) })

const two = dbQueryTwo.then(usr => ({
  key: usr.val
}))
.catch(err => { console.log(err) })

const three = dbQueryThree.then(usr => ({
  key: usr.val
}))
.catch(err => { console.log(err) })

Promise.all([one, two, three]).then(arr => {
  res.send(arr.filter(val => val !== undefined ))
})
```

`usr => ({ key: val })` is just short for `usr => { return { key: val } }`

Comment: Thank you very much! This really solved the problem!!